# Does Appium support Windows 6 Mobile OS?

Tags: windows, mobile, appium

Does Appium or selenium support the older version of Windows operating system for mobile ? Windows 6 operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Appium support page says](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#windows-application-ui-testing), that Windows apps testing uses Windows Application Driver, which is only available for Windows 10 devices, so Windows Mobile 6 is definitely not supported. [Selenium doesn't seem to support](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp#test-automation-for-web-applications) old (or any at all) mobile Windows neither (see "Supported Browsers and Platforms"). I tried searching a bit, but couldn't find any automated UI testing tools for old Windows Mobile at all.